# What is lazy meaning in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I went through multiple questions on stack overflow, but I didn't get an answer, that could define, what is "LAZY" keyword and why we are using it in Swift. I am very new to Swift, kindly explain.

Comment: Thank you very much.. i get it now.

Comment: glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word is used in two contexts.

- a lazy variable is a stored property that is calculated once but not until it is referenced for the first time. If I have this:

  ```
  var x: Int = someExpensiveFunction()
  ```

  it is calculated when its owning object is instantiated. If I do this

  ```
  lazy var x: Int = someExpensiveFunction()
  ```

  It is not calculated until the first time I want to use `x`.
- Lazy sequences are sequences in which some operations are calculated as they are needed. For example in this code

  ```
  [1, 2, 3].map { someExpensiveFunction($0) }
  ```

  The mapped sequence is fully calculated straight away. However in the following

  ```
   [1, 2, 3].lazy.map { someExpensiveFunction($0) }
  ```

  Each successive element of the final sequence is only calculated at the moment it is asked for e.g. by an iterator.

I suppose, technically, in the second case `lazy` is not being used as a keyword, but I include it for completeness.

Comment: Thank you very much... I get it now

Answer (score 3):

A `lazy` stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. You indicate a `lazy` stored property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.

*You must always declare a lazy property as a variable (with the var keyword), because its initial value might not be retrieved until after instance initialization completes. Constant properties must always have a value before initialization completes, and therefore cannot be declared as lazy.*

Checkout [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) reference for more information.

So basically, you can see the `lazy` as an just-in-time calculation of expensive work. These variables are created using a function you specify only when that variable is first requested. If it's never requested, the function is never run, so it does help save processing time.

Comment: Thank you very much.. i get it now

Answer (score 1):

The point of lazy properties is that they are computed only when they are first needed, after which their value is saved.

It avoids unnecessary initialization of a complex class, so they will only be created when you accessed them..

Have a look at this link to better understand it..

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Comment: Thank you very much.. i get it now